# Is there a single word that refers to a vagina secreting lubricant in response to sexual arousal?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm seeking a *single* word. An analogue is "salivate" which is what someone sometimes does when they experience hunger and refers to the mouth secreting liquid.

- "Elsa was hungry and began salivating"
- "Elsa was horny and began _________"

I'm looking for a word where the *person* is the subject, not the vulva. A mouth waters but a *person* salivates-- I am seeking the "salivate" analogue.

### Some Background

This is the best I've found so far, but "Elsa started sweating" is very likely to be misinterpreted.

> A woman’s vagina usually begins to lubricate shortly after stimulation— what looks like beads of sweat form all over the vaginal walls; this is sometimes called vaginal sweating. Just below the vaginal opening are the ducts that connect to the vulvovaginal glands, which secrete a few drops of thick fluid that contribute, along with the sweating of the vagina, to the lubrication of the vaginal opening.

*Kerner, Ian (2009-10-13). She Comes First: The Thinking Man's Guide to Pleasuring a Woman (Kerner) (Kindle Locations 816-819). HarperCollins. Kindle Edition.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no physiological term for this phenomenon. If you don't believe me, please read [this](http://www.bumc.bu.edu/sexualmedicine/physicianinformation/female-genital-anatomy/).

Salivation is an active process, as is lacrimation. Rhinorrhea (a runny nose) has no active verb either; the nose isn't mucorating, rhinorunning, or anything else. There is excess mucous production and gravity does the rest.

Similarly, the vasodilation and subsequent transudation of fluids in the vagina has no active verb. Nor does the tumescence of the penis (it's not "erecting".)**

There are slang words for these processes, but they are not akin to "salivation."

There aren't single words for everything under the sun.

**Edited to add** I was wrong. Tumesce is a verb. HT to @Frank.

Comment: argh! I fear you are right but I'll wait for a bit longer to see what else comes in. tyvm. Thanks also for the additional resources, will read.

Comment: No love for _tumefy_ or _tumefying_?

Comment: @Frank - Is that a real word? My approval or lack thereof has nothing to do the existence of a word. As I stated, there aren't single words for everything under the sun.

Comment: Yes it is - OED or http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tumefy

Comment: \*sequoia tumefies\* Thanks @Frank I'll definitely give it a whirl!

Comment: @Frank - Cool! I never heard it before, but then I'm not a urologist. Good word.

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell - and you wonder why some people say you're crude.

Comment: @medica https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word#Forms ;)

Comment: @medica - I not a urologist either, but I do have a special interest in that area ;)

Comment: @Frank "I'm not a urologist, but I play one on TV" ...or... "I'm not a urologist, but I pretend to be one when the waiting room is left unattended"

Comment: So is it "he tumesced" or "he tumefied?"

Answer (score 9):

***Elsa was horny and became wet***

If you can change the verb to "became", then this is probably the most 'tasteful' way to specify female sexual arousal in this sense. The first adjective eliminates any ambiguity.

I feel it is the most widely used present-day expression, found in almost all mediums - from novels to film. Given the presented sentence structures and limited context, I believe this may be more in line with what you are looking for.

Comment: "wet" is the most common expression, no woman I know says "I start lubricating whenever I see George Clooney, Johnny Depp, Orlando Bloom..." etc. It's "I get wet just thinking about GC; DJ; OB etc.etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Wait, back up- in your friend group, this comes up often enough that you only refer to these dudes by 2-letter abbreviations? ...Come to think of it, that would save a lot of time in my conversations as well. Although referring to Johnny Depp as "DJ" only makes sense within the context of the jokes I'm currently writing in my head.

Comment: DJ was a typo... :)

Answer (score 4):

[Cream.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cream)

> to have an orgasm, especially to ejaculate or experience glandular lubrication of the vagina

...I can't believe <del>it's not butter</del> I just helped answer this...

Comment: See? I'm doing my part to make the internet more comfortable with human sexuality. How many other people can say _that_?

Answer (score 2):

"Lubricating" seems quite understandable in context.  Better than "Sweating".

Comment: so "Elsa was horny and began lubricating"? thank you!

Comment: What was she lubricating? A squeaky door hinge?

Comment: @naomi - lol!!! Great visual.

Comment: NO!!!!! She began (to feel) lubricating??!! *Whaaat*?

Answer (score 0):

The verb phrase "became wet" though is a stative passive, which indicates state rather than action. (Also salivating and sweating are no more active processes than say.. hardening or moistening... and certainly less so than lacrimating. And all describe involuntary physiological responses to some stimulus)

Unfortunately, I don't know any canonical phrase for the active form.. but possibly this will be of interest:

pegspot.blogspot.com/2006/04/discharge-by-any-other-name.html?m=1

Kind of I like the idea of using libate..

"Elsa was horny and began libating" ???

(The word labiate, though is an adjective already.means "having lips", labi coming from latin labium (lip) so using the suffix -ate as a verb form just sounds like "to lip" as in to engage with the lips, or to furnish something with lips...  which, to me at least, makes no sense. But then I'm not in charge of English...)

Comment: "Libate" means to pour.

Answer (score 0):

If the process can be called “transudation of fluids,” why can’t you say a woman is transudating? “Transudate” is a legitimate verb.

Comment: Hi Porthos, welcome to English Language & Usage. If you think you might use our site again (and I hope you do!), please make sure you take the [Tour].  :-)

Answer (score -3):

OK I'm gonna go right in and answer this for you:

She began glistening.

Comment: That's also used to describe a woman that is perspiring in other non-vaginal places.

Comment: Plus, it's still about as general as "lubricating", and arguably worse (because if a woman's reaching climax in darkness, no glistening is occurring). Waterfalls and rocks glisten. My first assumption, if someone said "she's glistening", would not be sexual (unless their inflection made that insinuation obvious- but then, if they said "she's making herself some toast" with enough inflection that could also sound sexual).

Comment: *"The little Karin served/ Within the young king's hall; She glistened like a star,/ Among the maidens all."* - Henry Wadsworth Longfellow.

Comment: I like it! It's true that it's vague/non-specific but it's not as *common* as sweating, so "Elsa was horny & began glistening" would more likely communicate the message than "Elsa was horny and began **sweating**" which is likely to be interpreted as literally just sweating.

Comment: @medica Perhaps, but you've always got to be suspicious given the guy's middle name was "Wadsworth" and his last name was "Longfellow". His name is a Hamming distance of zero from the nearest porn equivalent.

Comment: @ParthianShot - OK, you have totally given me a new outlook on the man and his poem!!! :D

Comment: @ParthianShot It seems my meaning wasn't clear-- I am referring to secretion of vaginal lubrication that occurs when a woman *becomes aroused*, i.e. as a precursor to some sort of sex. If a vagina did not become lubricated until after orgasm that would make PIV sex quite... it would probably necessitate the use of synthetic lubricant. (I do not posses a vagina however so I could very well be mistaken here.)

Comment: When you say she began "glistening" I imagine her smiling emphatically or something, like "beaming" or "glowing".

Comment: If the exact context is “Elsa became horny and started glistening”, I would interpret _glistening_ to mean that beads of sweat started to form on Elsa’s skin in general—i.e., just general sweating.

Answer (score -3):

I'm going to go with the Urban Dictionary suggestion, which is [grool](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=grool).

Technically, *grool* is a noun, but despite [what Calvin says](https://bellsiebooks.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/verbing_weirds_language.gif), I think you can use it as a verb.

Comment: Don't you mean “like Calvin says”?

Answer (score -4):

I know this is an old thread, but I recently discovered a french word which describes exactly what english fails:
Cyprine.

Comment: Welcome to *English* Language & Usage. As [cyprine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cyprine) has another meaning in English, it can't be used so it doesn't really provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @Glorfindel It may be a wrong answer, but clearly it is an answer.

Comment: @MetaEd I think it's an orange as described by Shog [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/295232), hence Not An Answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel Shog, from your linked page: "if the text of the post contains an honest attempt at answering the question, then it is an answer - so don't flag it otherwise"

Comment: Laura - the asker is looking for a verb. I don't speak French but I get the impression you're offering a noun?